# how is this conversion possible?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I was reading Morris Mano's - Computer System Architechture and My problem is the simplification of `F = AB + A'C` which was:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSkLkb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which was simplified to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Dsfc.png)</sup>

I am confused why NOT1 was replaced with NAND4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am confused why NOT1 was replaced with NAND4?

First, it sould be clear why it was legitimate to do so - a NAND gate with the inputs joined is just an inverter.

To understand *the motivation why* it was done, it's useful to look at the final OR gate preceded by inverters on each input, and realize that DeMorgan's theorem shows that the OR with inverted inputs can be replaced by a NAND gate.

At that point you have a circuit made of 4 NAND gates, and in traditional 74xx logic families, NAND gates happen to come four to an IC package... ie, the 74xx00 is a quad two input NAND.